# In Django not getting the requisite response

Tags: django, python-2.7

Here is my Server code which on execution is generating  500 error.

#views.py

import json

```
def registered_users_number(request):
    if not request.is_ajax():
       raise Http404

     usercount_today =  User.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM core_user WHERE DATE(reg_date) =   DATE(NOW())")
     print usercount_today
     response_data['result'] = usercount_today
     response_data['message']='You messed up'
     return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

I guess Some syntax issues are there which I can figure out on account of my noviceness in Django and Python.

Also the print usercount_today is giving :- RawQuerySet: 'SELECT * FROM core_user WHERE DATE(reg_date) = DATE(NOW())'.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Can you include the traceback?

Comment: The traceback is

    <RawQuerySet: 'SELECT * FROM core_user WHERE DATE(reg_date) = DATE(NOW())'>
[31/Jan/2013 14:18:19] "GET /siteadmin/registered_users_number HTTP/1.1" 500 11364

Comment: That's not the exception traceback. Have you set DEBUG=True in your Django settings? You'd an error page that shows the exception traceback. However, if it is an Ajax request you're running you don't see the page, you'd need to inspect the Ajax response in the browser's developer tools (network panel in Chrome for instance). Did you setup Django logging, in case DEBUG=False you should see the traceback in the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone.

I got it. It was nothing but lack of familiarity with Django.

Here is the changes that i did.

## views.py

```
def registered_users_number(request):   
    from django.db import connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    if not request.is_ajax():
         raise Http404

    cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM core_user WHERE DATE(reg_date) = DATE(NOW())")
    usercount_today = cursor.fetchone()  
    print(usercount_today)
    response_data = simplejson.dumps({"count": usercount_today})
    return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="application/json")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have three issues in code:

1. Error on declaring `response_data`. Before line `response_data['result'] = usercount_today` you should define `response_data = {}`
2. Why do you need to `print usercount_today`? It's a server code and python doesn't print this line into HttpResponse.
3. Do you really need raw sql query on user objects retrieving? Why don't you use django [ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) in this line? It's not only about code style, but also about Django: since [1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) it saves time objects in a specific way in db, and you should use date-aware datetime objects instead `DATE(NOW())`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I will be using Django ORM. But what do you mean by date-aware datetime objects, I dont know about them.

The first error that you are pointing is that I am not formatting my JSON data correctly.

I am printing this line (print usercount_today) to see whether my query is giving me correct result, I am expecting this to displayed on Django shell.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing some more of your code it is not entirely possible to tell but it seems like you are using raw SQL when you could more easily harness the power of the Django ORM.

To me it looks like you could do it much more cleanly along the following lines:

```
import datetime

def registered_users_number(request):
    usercount_today = User.objects.filter(reg_date__gte=datetime.date.today()).count()
    response_data = simplejson.dumps({"count": usercount_today})
    return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="application/json")
```

The main problem is we can't see your User model and it's hard to tell whether reg_date is already a datetime field or not. If not, I'd suggest using something like `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` for your reg_date field and then you can easily use the ORM like above.

Comment: Yes reg_date is a datetime field.